# "As much as" / "autant (de) que": amount or number of times?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

(Level A2 here, so will ask in English, hoping that's fine.)

I'd like to say *"we pack our backpacks as heavy as we wish them to be"* (in response to the correspondent's backpack having ended up being "trop plein", as always). DeepL and Google Translate put out various suggestions, also depending on what source language I choose. Some of these suggestions include "autant", which is new vocabulary to me and seems to come in two variants: "autant que" or "autant de ... que".

With the newfound knowledge, I tried to phrase a sentence myself:

> On faisait nos sacs autant qu'on voulait les porter.

Unfortunately, feeding that back into the translation machines, it looks like it's not what I intended it to be, instead yielding *"we packed our bags as much as we wanted to carry them"* from both websites.

- What is the actual, idiomatic way of expressing what I want to say?
- May "autant" be used for *both* "as **heavy** as" as well as "as **often** as"?

As an aside:

- In German, "to carry a heavy backpack" is often used as a metaphor for "to have had a difficult life with many hardships". Is the same true for French, or, if not, what is the commonly used figure of speech?

Comment: as heavy as we wish them to be is *very stilted* in English. Pack a bag is faire une valise, not a sac. If they are grocery bags, or shopping bags, we fill them. Then, they are sacs we'd fill them up as much as possible.

Comment: "sac" was simply the word the other person (a native speaker) had used. they knew i would understand it to mean "backpack" from context. as for the stiltedness, yes, that's by intention (two people who enjoy playing with language, using sarcasm, creating double meanings, etc) so you saw that correctly.

Comment: @Lambie "fais ton sac" means "pack your bag", no doubt there.

Comment: @njzk2 You misunderstood me: In English (not French), the OP originally had: **pack our bag**, which would be: faire sa valise. Because **in English**, **bag** is not **a backpack**.  But the OP as you can now see has changed it to "backpack". Also, please read the OP's comment.

Comment: (Apologies for the confusion ... felt it best to change it after having had it pointed out to me in comments)

Comment: @Lambie there are all sorts of travel bags that are neither suitcases nor backpacks, though. Oddly enough, "Pack your bags" (plural) would be "fais tes bagages" ou "fais tes valises" - no "sac" involved here - but "pack your bag" (singular) can definitely be "fais ton sac" (and, also "fais ta valise").

My point is: a bag, in English, can be a travel bag such as a duffel bag, or a gym bag, or even a messenger bag.

Comment: @Lambie I think the confusion is that the OP originally had "pack a backpack", which can translate as "faire un sac", loosing the backpack context, which in turn if it is translated back should not be "pack a bag", because of the implicit backpack that was lost in translation

Comment: @njzk2 **No, the OP did not orginally have "pack a backpack". They had **pack a bag**. Anyway, you are completely ignoring what I am saying re the OP, the original post and my original comment. The rest is not relevant. This was the original sentence: **I'd like to say "we pack our bags as heavy as we wish them to be**. Please try to take into account what the other person says. Thanks.

Comment: @Lambie "Pack a bag is faire une valise, not a sac" you're ignoring that this is not true, because pack one's bag also means faire son sac. As I indicated, there are bags in English that are used for travel, and that can be packed as well as a suitcase.

Comment: @Lambie in "we pack our bags", there's not enough context to decide between translating as "nous faisons nos bagages / valises / sacs"

Comment: @njzk2 Last time: I was talking about the **English**: pack a bag is faire une valise. We don't say pack a bag for other types of bags IN ENGLISH.  Like handbags, grocery bags, garbage bags etc. etc. Read the OP's **first comment**.

Comment: @Lambie in French, une valise is a square box in which you put stuff for travel. In English it is called a suitcase. Packing a bag in English means packing stuff in a container suitable for traveling, which can be a suitcase, a duffel bag, or a backpack (for example, carry-on bags are often backpacks). I know that one doesn't pack a grocery bag.

Comment: @njzk2 Forget. My original remark was to the OP and they admitted they were "playing around". You come along and tell me what they said originally (pack a backpack) and you were wrong: the original post was: pack a bag, a bag. You also are deliberately ignoring what I say. We pack our bags in regular English refers to luggage. Not anything else. faire son sac like sac à dos is NOT pack a bag.

Comment: @Lambie why do you not consider a backpack as a piece of luggage? How would you say in English "faire son sac" when referring to a backpack, in a context of imminent travel?

Comment: **The original thing was not backpack. It was bag. Bag. Bag." And bag is not sac à dos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the actual, idiomatic way of expressing what I want to say?

- *Nous faisons/remplissons nos sacs **comme** nous le souhaitons.*
- *On fait nos sacs **aussi** lourds **qu'** on le souhaite.*
- *Nous remplissons nos sacs d'**autant** d'affaires **que** nous le souhaitons.*
- *On met **autant** d'affaires dans nos sacs **qu'** on le souhaite.*

These are only a few examples, I can add more if needed. By the way, I believe the most accurate way to say *litterally* what you mean would be :

- *Nous faisons nos sacs de telle manière à ce qu'ils soient **aussi lourds que** nous le voulons.*
- *Nous remplissons nos sacs d'**autant d'affaires que nous souhaitons qu'ils soient lourds**.*

But it really does not feel right to me : the first one is fine in a written conversation and okay orally speaking (but still not heard much), but the second one sounds like a dissonance to me (i.e. it sounds wrong even though it is grammatically correct).

---

> May "autant" be used for both "as heavy as" as well as "as often as"?

No it cannot. "Autant" can be used for an enumerable quantity, "affaires" in this case :

- *J'ai **autant** d'affaires que toi.* ("I have as much things as you.")
- *Je prends **autant** de pâtes que lui.* ("I'll have as much pasta as him.")
- *Nous aurons **autant** de temps que vous pour terminer le défi.* ("We have as much time to complete the challenge as you.")

But for an adjective, "lourd" here, it is not grammatically correct to use it. We would use "aussi" or "comme" (for the most common cases) :

- *Mon sac est **aussi** lourd que le tien.* ("My bag is as heavy as yours.")
- *Mon frère est **aussi** grand que moi.* ("My brother is as tall as you.")
- *Vous n'êtes pas riches **comme** eux le sont.* ("You are not as rich as they are.")
- *Prenez autant de temps que vous voulez.* ("Take as much time as you need.")

---

It is the same difference between "as many as" and "as much as" : one is for enumerable quantities, the other for non-enumerable quantities :

- *As many people* / *As many times* / *As many potatoes*
- *As much time* / *As much soup* / *As much blood*

---

---

Point related to the meanings of *[lourd](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lourd)*, and associated expressions :

- When speaking about someone, *Il est **aussi lourd que toi**.* ("He is as heavy as you.") can have several meanings : "You both weight the same." (literal) or "He is **as annoying as you**." (figurative).
- *Il supporte un gros/**lourd bagage émotionnel**.* ("He carries a heavy emotional baggage."), *Elle s'est constituée un solide bagage de compétences pour son travail.* ("She accumulated a good amount of skills for her work."), etc. Here, the [adjective + baggage] group means "a whole lot of", and the positive/negative variation depends on the adjective, *lourd* ("heavy") being then understood as "**overwhelming**", "**exhausting**", or even "**devastating**".
- Recently, a new use of "lourd" has been observed (amoung the youth, mostly), here are some daily examples : "Ce film est **super lourd** !" ("This movie is super heavy!"), "**Lourd de fou**, ton outfit !" ("Your outfit is crazy heavy !"). We could respectively translate those as "This movie is so good!" and "You are so nicely dressed up!". We are looking here at a very positive use of the adjective, to describe something that is **very highly appreciated**.
- *Il subira une **opération** chirurgicale **assez lourde**.* ("He will undergo a heavy surgery operation.") where *lourd.e* can be replaced by *important*, thus meaning "He will undergo **major surgery**.".

Comment: Thank you, Marck! These are already plenty of examples, especially since two of them are constructed using the word that the question is about in the first place. Both your and KFK's examples will give me something to chew on for a while...

Comment: @Marck - Juste une petite note, comme l'anglais mentionne _heavy_, je pense que mentionner le poids d'une façon ou d'une autre en français préserverait le mieux qu'il s'agit d'une question ... de poids :-) Par exemple, _Nous mettons autant d'affaires dans nos sacs que nous le souhaitons_ perd un peu la notion de poids, à mon avis.

Comment: @Frank merci, j'ai rajouté quelques petites choses :) Le deuxième exemple mentionne le poids avec "lourds", ça ne convient pas ?

Comment: @Marck Si, ça convient très bien. Par choix personnel, je serai resté autour de cet exemple-là, mais pas de problème.

Comment: Bags ici, ce sont des valises et pas des sacs...to pack a bag. Faire une valise. bags, like shopping bags are typically filled.

Comment: @Lambie on peut aussi dire "faire son sac" ! :)

Comment: En générale, on remplit un sac à dos and on fait un valise.

Comment: En fait, dans cette utilisation, on peut utiliser beaucoup de verbes qui sont synonymes (pour ce cas-ci), et ce, pour "valise" **et** "sac" : *faire*, *emplir*, *remplir*, *boucler*, *préparer*, *terminer*, etc.

Comment: « Nous remplissons nos sacs d'autant d'affaires que nous souhaitons qu'ils soient lourds. » : pas une phrase correcte ; on ne dit pas « lourd de ces affaires », « ces sacs sont lourds de beaucoup d'affaires » (par exemple).

Comment: « Nous aurons autant de temps pour terminer le défi que vous. » : plutôt lourd.  « Nous aurons autant de temps que vous pour terminer le défi. »

Comment: I just noticed there's a thing at play here which I didn't think to include yesterday. In my mother tongue, German, when you say something like: "oof, he's carrying a heavy backpack", it means: "he has a lot to deal with in his life" (often the conversation might be about a difficult childhood where terrible things might have happened). Now I'm wondering if the "heavy backpack" metaphore would work the same way in French...

Comment: @Sixtyfive may I add this meaning in my answer ? It could be interesting to add it in your question too :)

Comment: Of course @Marck, I like having it there. Will rephrase question!

Comment: @Mark Off topic but it is unfortunate that you replace the idiomatic subject *on* used in the OP's attempt with the far less idiomatic *nous* that no native use in speech anymore.

Comment: Sixtyfive I've added some precision, if you want to have a look ;)

@jlliagre you are right, thank you for noticing, I edited my answer to give more versatile examples

Answer (score 4):

I can see two intended meanings in the context you describe:

- you and I decided to pack our bags as heavy as we can, subject to physical constraints (objects need to fit inside, humans must be able to carry them around, etc.)
- each person chooses how much they carry, and should only blame themselves if their bag is too heavy

Idiomatic translations of the first meaning would be

- *On remplit / nous remplissons nos sacs au maximum.* We fill our bags to capacity.
- *On remplit nos sacs autant qu’on peut.* We fill our bags as much as we can. Here, *autant* refers to an undifferentiated quantity; it probably refers to weight or volume, but in another context it could even refer to frequency (i.e. "we fill our bags as often as possible").
- *On met le maximum de choses dans nos sacs.* We put as many things as possible in our bags.

For the second meaning, assuming an indirect approach is needed (i.e. no "tu as choisi..."), I would say

- *Chacun a choisi combien il voulait porter.* Everyone chose how much they wished to carry.
- *On a mis chacun dans nos sacs ce qu’on voulait porter.* We each put in our bags what we wished to carry. (Slightly convoluted, probably more idiomatic in a text message than orally.)

For either meaning I would use some version of *remplir le sac* (fill (up) the bag) rather than *faire son sac* (pack (up) one’s bag). *Faire son sac* is a fixed expression to describe one step in the process of going on a trip, it does not work well with additional modifiers.

Comment: Thank you KFK, especially also for talking about "remplir le sac" vs "faire son sac" as well as dividing the answer up between the two possible meanings. For what it's worth, it was a text conversation and the intention was to use the bag as a metaphore for life.

I wish it were possible to accept multiple answers. Only accepted Marck's because before scrolling down, I hadn't seen yours yet, and then couldn't find anything that would have made one answer better than the other in any significant way.

Comment: @KFK - Peut-être par préférence, j'aurais tendance à essayer de préserver le problème du _poids_ qui est mentionné dans l'anglais _heavy_ :-)